# There are 4 Categorical Propositions and the Square of Oppositions summarizes the relations between the propositions. How are the relations proved?

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

The square of oppositions is

[image: Square of Opposition]

and there are some implications between related propositions as shown in the following image:

[image: Square of Opposition].

What are the proofs of those implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The 4 Categorical Propositions

The four categorical propositions, denoted $\mathsf{A}$, $\mathsf{E}$, $\mathsf{I}$, and $\mathsf{O}$ are:

|  | In words | Abbr | In notation | Quantifier | Affirm/Neg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\mathsf{A}$ | Each S is P | SaP | $\forall x(Sx \implies Px)$ | Universal | Affirmative |
| $\mathsf{E}$ | Each S is non-P | SeP | $\forall x(Sx \implies \lnot Px)$ | Universal | Negative |
| $\mathsf{I}$ | Some S is P | SiP | $\exists x(Sx \land Px)$ | Particular | Affirmative |
| $\mathsf{O}$ | Some S is non-P | SoP | $\exists x(Sx \land \lnot Px)$ | Particular | Negative |

> *Table generated with [TablesGenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com).*

## The Square of Oppositions

The **square of oppositions** summarizes the relations between the 4 categorical propositions, $\mathsf{A}$, $\mathsf{E}$, $\mathsf{I}$, and $\mathsf{O}$. In the sections that follow, we will explain each of those relations.

[image: Square of Opposition]

> *The image uses different, but equivalent, wording.
> The grayed out relations only hold when $\exists x(Sx)$ as we will show in the following sections.
> Not shown is the superalternation relation which is the reverse of the subalternation relation.
> Image attribution: [Watchduck (a.k.a. Tilman Piesk)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Square_of_opposition,_set_diagrams.svg), Public domain, via Wikimedia Commons*

### $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are Contradictories 
 $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are Contradictories

**Contradictory** propositions are negations of each other. $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are contradictory. $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are contradictory. In notation,

$$
\mathsf{A} \equiv \lnot \mathsf{O} \\
\mathsf{I} \equiv \lnot \mathsf{E}
$$

##### Proof:

> $$
> \lnot \mathsf{A} \equiv \lnot \forall x(Sx \implies Px) \\
> \equiv \exists x(\lnot (Sx \implies Px)) \\
> \equiv \exists x(\lnot (\lnot Sx \lor Px)) \\
> \equiv \exists x(Sx \land \lnot Px)) \\
> \equiv \mathsf{O} \\
> $$

This proves $\mathsf{A} \equiv \lnot \mathsf{O}$. The proof for $\mathsf{I} \equiv \lnot \mathsf{E}$ is similar.

### If there's no $x$ that satisfies $Sx$, then $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are vacuously true and $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are false

A conditional proposition "$S \implies ...$" is **vacuously true** when $S$ is false. Likewise,  a universally quantified proposition "$\forall x(Sx \implies ...)$" is vacuously true when "$S$ is false for all $x$" $\equiv \forall x(\lnot Sx) \equiv \lnot \exists x(Sx)$. $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are universally quantified conditional propositions of the form $\forall x(Sx \implies ...)$. Thus, $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are vacuously true when $\lnot \exists x(Sx)$.

A conjunction "$S \land ...$" is false when $S$ is false. Likewise, an existentially quantified  proposition "$\exists x(Sx \land ...)$" is false when "$S$ is false for all $x$" $\equiv \forall x(\lnot Sx) \equiv \lnot \exists x(Sx)$.  $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are existentially quantified propositions of the form $\exists x(Sx \land ...)$. Thus, $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are false when $\lnot \exists x(Sx)$.

In notation,

$$
\lnot \exists x(Sx) \implies \mathsf{A} \land \mathsf{E} \\
\lnot \exists x(Sx) \implies \lnot \mathsf{I} \land \lnot \mathsf{O} \\
$$

##### Proof

> Let $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{F}$ denote constant true and constant false, respectively.
> $\lnot \exists x(Sx) \equiv \forall x(\lnot Sx) \equiv \forall x(\lnot Sx \equiv \mathbf{T}x) \equiv \forall x(Sx \equiv \mathbf{F}x) \implies S = \mathbf{F}$

> $\forall x(\mathbf{F}x \implies Zx)$ for arbitrary $Z$.
> $\forall x(Sx \implies Zx)$ for arbitrary $Z$.
> With $Z = \mathbf{P}$, we have $\forall x(Sx \implies Zx) \equiv \mathsf{A}$. This proves $\mathsf{A}$.
> With $Z = \lnot \mathbf{P}$, we have $\forall x(Sx \implies Zx) \equiv \mathsf{E}$. This proves $\mathsf{E}$.

> $\exists x(\mathbf{F}x \land Z)$ is **false** for arbitary $Z$.
> $\exists x(\mathbf{S}x \land Z)$ is **false** for arbitary $Z$.
> With $Z = \mathbf{P}$, we have "$\exists x(Sx \land Zx)$ is **false**" $\equiv \lnot \mathsf{I}$. This proves $\lnot \mathsf{I}$.
> With $Z = \lnot \mathbf{P}$, we have "$\exists x(Sx \land Zx)$ is **false**" $\equiv \lnot \mathsf{O}$. This proves $\lnot \mathsf{O}$.

##### Example

Let $Sx$ and $Px$ be the propositions that *"$x$ is a unicorn"* and *"$x$ is a mammal"*, respectively. In words,

- $\mathsf{A}:=$ *"Each unicorn is a mammal."*
- $\mathsf{E}:=$ *"Each unicorn is a non-mammal."*

Since *"Unicorns do not exist."* (i.e. $\lnot\exists x(Sx)$), $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are each vacuously true.

### If there's $x$ that satisfies $Sx$, then we have subalternation and superalternation

| Subalternation | Superalternation |
| --- | --- |
| $\mathsf{I}$ is the **subaltern** of $\mathsf{A}$ | $\mathsf{A}$ is the **superaltern** of $\mathsf{I}$. |
| $\mathsf{O}$ is the **subaltern** of $\mathsf{E}$ | $\mathsf{E}$ is the **subaltern** of $\mathsf{O}$. |

> Side note: Subalternation and superalternation are sometimes called **subimplication**  and **superimplication**, respectively.

Provided that $\exists x(Sx)$, the following implications hold:[^1]

| Subalternation | Superalternation |
| --- | --- |
| $\mathsf{A} \implies \mathsf{I}$ | $\lnot \mathsf{I} \implies \lnot \mathsf{A}$ |
| $\mathsf{E} \implies \mathsf{O}$ | $\lnot \mathsf{O} \implies \lnot \mathsf{E}$ |

which can be summarized as:

$$
\lnot \mathsf{A} \lor \mathsf{I} \\
\lnot \mathsf{E} \lor \mathsf{O}
$$

##### Proof:

> Note,  $\mathsf{A} \implies \mathsf{I} \equiv \lnot \mathsf{I} \implies \lnot \mathsf{A} \equiv \lnot \mathsf{A} \lor \mathsf{I}$, so it is enough to only prove one of these.
> We are given $\exists x(Sx)$ and $\mathsf{A} := \forall x(Sx \implies Px)$ and must derive $\mathsf{I}$.
> Let $x_0$ be a particular $x$ that satisfies $S$ (i.e. $Sx_0$).
> By $\mathsf{A}$, $x_0$ also satisfies $P$ (i.e. $Px_0$).
> Thus $\exists x(Sx \land Px) \equiv \mathsf{I}$.

This proves $\mathsf{A} \implies \mathsf{I}$. The proof for $\mathsf{E} \implies \mathsf{O}$ and its equivalents is similar.

### If there's $x$ that satisfies $Sx$, then $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are contraries

**Contrary** propositions cannot both be true; however, they can both be false. If there's $x$ that satisfies $Sx$, then $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are contrary.

Provided that $\exists x(Sx)$, the following implications hold:[^1]

$$
\mathsf{A} \implies \lnot \mathsf{E} \\
\mathsf{E} \implies \lnot \mathsf{A}
$$

##### Proof

> Note,  $\mathsf{A} \implies \lnot \mathsf{E} \equiv \mathsf{E} \implies \lnot \mathsf{A}$, so it is enough to only prove one of these.
> We are given $\exists x(Sx)$ and $\mathsf{A}$ and must derive $\lnot \mathsf{E}$.
> $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are contradictory, i.e. $\mathsf{A} \equiv \lnot \mathsf{O}$. We are given $\mathsf{A}$, therefore $\lnot \mathsf{O}$.
> $\mathsf{O}$ is the subaltern of $\mathsf{E}$ and $\exists x(Sx)$, therefore $\lnot \mathsf{O} \implies \lnot \mathsf{E}$.
> Therefore $\lnot \mathsf{E}$.

This proves $\mathsf{A} \implies \lnot \mathsf{E}$.

##### Example of $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ each being false with $\exists x(Sx)$

Let $Sx$ and $Px$ be the propositions that *"$x$ is a man"* and *"$x$ is white"*, respectively.

- $\mathsf{A}:=$ *"Each man is a white."*
- $\mathsf{E}:=$ *"Each man is a non-white."*

Since not every man is white, but some men are white, $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are each false.

##### Example of $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ each being false with $\lnot \exists x(Sx)$

Let $Sx$ and $Px$ be the propositions that *"$x$ is a unicorn"* and *"$x$ is white"*, respectively.

- $\mathsf{A}:=$ *"Each unicorn is a white."*
- $\mathsf{E}:=$ *"Each unicorn is a non-white."*

Since *"Unicorns do not exist."*, $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are each false.

### If there's $x$ that satisfies $Sx$, then $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are subcontraries

**Subontrary** propositions cannot both be false; however, they can both be true. If there's $x$ that satisfies $Sx$, then $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are subcontrary.

Provided that $\exists x(Sx)$, the following implications hold:[^1]

$$
\lnot \mathsf{I} \implies \mathsf{O} \\
\lnot \mathsf{O} \implies \mathsf{I}
$$

##### Proof

> Note,  $\lnot \mathsf{I} \implies \mathsf{O} \equiv \lnot \mathsf{O} \implies \mathsf{I}$, so it is enough to only prove one of these.
> We are given $\exists x(Sx)$ and $\lnot \mathsf{I}$ and must derive $\mathsf{O}$.
> $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are contradictory, i.e. $\mathsf{I} \equiv \lnot \mathsf{E}$. We are given $\lnot \mathsf{I}$, therefore $\mathsf{E}$.
> $\mathsf{E}$ is the superaltern of $\mathsf{O}$ and $\exists x(Sx)$, therefore $\mathsf{E} \implies \mathsf{O}$.
> Therefore $\mathsf{O}$.

This proves $\lnot \mathsf{I} \implies \mathsf{O}$.

##### Example of $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ each being true with $\exists x(Sx)$

Let $Sx$ and $Px$ be the propositions that *"$x$ is a man"* and *"$x$ is white"*, respectively.

- $\mathsf{I}:=$ *"Some man is white."*
- $\mathsf{O}:=$ *"Some man is a non-white."*

Since some men are white and some men are not white, $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are each true.

##### Example of $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ each being true with $\lnot \exists x(Sx)$

This is not possible. When $\lnot \exists x(Sx)$, $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are each false. See[^1].

### Summary of Relations/Implications

The implications we found for each relation are summarized in the  following image:
[image: Square of Opposition]

> *The image uses different, but equivalent, wording.
> Not shown is the superalternation relation/implication which is the reverse of the subalternation relation (i.e. a false $\mathsf{I}$ implies a false $\mathsf{O}$ and likewise, a false $\mathsf{O}$ implies a false $\mathsf{E}$.*
> **Recall that the contrary, subcontrary, subalternation, and superalternation relations/implications only hold when $\exists x(Sx)$.**

---

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/). Some of the markdown may not render properly on StackExchange (e.g. footnotes [^1]).

[^1]: By contrast, when $\lnot \exists x(Sx)$, none of the implications hold. Instead we have $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are each vacuously true and $\mathsf{I}$ and $\mathsf{O}$ are each false.